# Using JavaScript to open link in a new window

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I know that this is beyond simple but unfortunately by programming skills are really bad...

I'm using a content slider for Sharepoint made by [Mark Rackley](http://www.paitgroup.com/the-ultimate-content-slider-for-sharepoint/#comment-13158) that uses Unslider.

The thing is that it only opens the links in the same window... I know that I have to change the function below so that it uses "window.open" instead of "window.location"... but I cannot make it work...  a little help please :)

```
call2.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    for(index in data.d.results)
    {
    $("#PAITSlides").append("<li><div onclick='window.location=\"" + 
                             data.d.results[index].LinkLocation.Url + "\"' 
                             style=\"background-image: url('"+data.d.results[index].BackgroundImageLocation.Url + "');\" 
                             class='PAITSlide'>"+data.d.results[index].Description +" 
                             </div></li>"
                           );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using div with onclick method you can try to use

```
<a href="yourURL" target="_blank"></a>
```

The target attribute has 2 possible values:

- _blank: It will open in a new window/tab
- _self: It will open in the same window

### Edit

Your code should be like this:

```
call2.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
            for(index in data.d.results)
            {
                    $("#PAITSlides").append("<li><div style=\"background-image: url('"+data.d.results[index].BackgroundImageLocation.Url +
                    "');\" class='PAITSlide'><a href=\""+  data.d.results[index].LinkLocation.Url+"\" target=\"_blank\">"+data.d.results[index].Description+"</a></div></li>");
            }
```

Comment: tried to change the code without the div but it doesn't work, possibly due to sharepoint structure or something...

Comment: I've been using sharepoint online and I've never encounter with this problem, can you tell us how do you put the <a> tag?

Comment: I'm not a programmer so I just tried to change the div for the <a> tag, but since the function as several variables for the URL being passed as well as the image (both from a list in sharepoint) I cannot change from div to <a> ref...

Comment: It is not that simple, because <a> and <div> doesn't have the same attributes, I've just edited my answer to show you how you code should be. Can you tell me if it is what you've done and if not, can you try to put it and see if it works? @JoaoHenriques

Comment: Unfortunately no, but many thanks for the suggestion... the slider breaks and all the images in the list are displayed at the same time, it also appears a text saying "null" above the image that I can click and it will open to the new tab.

Comment: And window.open didn't work? I mean, you can use window.open('yourURL', '_blank');

Comment: I'm working on that now, it seems windows.location uses a equal sign and windows.open uses "()", still figuring out, at the moment it doesn't gives any error but it does nothing when I click on the images also.

Answer (score 0):

You should add target="_blank"

Comment: Is it possible to use window.location and add the "_blank" somewhere?